# What DTP does Wikipedia use for PDF export?

Tags: wikipedia, export, pdf, text-formatting

When viewing any Wikipedia article, it is possible to export the article to a number of formats, including PDF.  My instinct told me they would use some TeX system (plainTeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, etc.), but it doesn't quite fit the bill.  The result looks 'nice'-ish, but nowhere near TeX's standards.

So, if not TeX, what does Wikipedia use?

Comment: @Downvoter(s?): This question *is* within the scope of the FAQ: Wikipedia *behaves like an application* offering advanced editing, subscribing, sharing, import, and export facilities for information dissemination.  This is a question regarding the implementation of this system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about `Special:Book`, then that comes from [the Collection extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCollection). That in turn uses several backends for generating the various formats. For PDF, [the PDF Writer extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPDF_Writer) is used:

> The PDF Writer uses the Python Reportlab libraries to generate PDF based on a DOM derived from parsing mediawiki-markup using the mwlib parser.

Comment: Just makes me wonder why they chose this over an honestly better solution; markup-markup is generally an easy transformation (especially with the logical markup in LaTeX).  But I suppose since the work was already done, no need to reinvent the wheel twice.  Meh.